# Configurations for a php application

Tags: php, configuration

Well am creating a php based application therefore I wish to accompany it with a configuration file. However the configuration will have a few variables which will be updated once in a while.

Therefore how can I read a file and update a specific variable in it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well yes I have done a database table. I put the settings, but every time I have to query the database which makes my app a bit slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to define your own configuration in .ini files and parse them with [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: I like thank you but the major reason for my asking was a way to update the configuration file. I will review parse_ini_file() perhaps it has the feature